# Combine 2 update querys in a single query - performance

Tags: mysql, performance, database-performance, query-performance

Im programming a favourite function.

For example we have multiple adresses and can choose one as favourite.

At the moment i got 2 querys to do this job:

```
UPDATE userdata
SET maindata = 0
WHERE 
cid = :id;

UPDATE userdata
SET maindata = 1
WHERE 
cid = :id AND id = :id2
LIMIT 1
```

In the first query i make all adresses as "no favourite" and in the second one i make the new choosen adress the favourite one.

Is there any way to imrpove this query or rewrite both into 1 ? Or even a better solution ?

Comment: You shouldn't try to improve the performance of something that isn't slow.

Comment: `UPDATE userdata SET maindata = (id = :id2) WHERE cid = :id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a single query you could use a case when (or an if)

```
update  userdata 
set maindate = case when id = :id2 then 1 
                else 0 end 
where  cid = :id;
```

for performance  Be sure you have a proper index on userdata  columns (cid, id)

and the number of rows  scanned  should be the same for the first wuary  ..but in this way you avoid the second ..

eventually  try create a composite index

```
 create index myidx1 on userdata(cid, id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer its working nice, would the query perform better like that ?

Comment: I checked the performance with Explain and it looks like the performance might be even worse, because all rows in the table have to be checked instead with 2 querys only so much rows like adresses exist for this user. If the table is big it would be better to use 2 querys then the case one.

Comment: @delato468  answer  updated .. with some suggestion

Comment: i have a primary key on id and a index on cid, and according to explain all 5 addresses are involved instead of 2. I think the problem is the case function is getting executed earlier then the where clause

Comment: no you need  a composite index   the query can use only one index for each table so  .. try create index  myidx1 on userdata(cid, id)   ..

Comment: Oh your right, with composite index it is working perfect, sorry and thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE userdata SET maindata = (case when cid = id AND id = id2 then 1 else 0 end);
```

This will help. I am not sure of your query but this will help. let me know if you looking something different...

Comment: `cid = id` is kind of random and not what OP asked for. `:id` and `:id2` are (named) placeholders like `?` used in some clients like PHP-PDO.